# Is there a way to make the default NSDragOperation Move and still allow Copy?

Tags: swift, cocoa, drag-and-drop

In some applications (GarageBand for example) the initial drag operation is Move, and Copy is supported if you press the Option key while dragging.
I have tried several things but have not had any success.  If .Copy is specified in the operation mask it always becomes the default operation.  Is this possible?

```
    func draggingSession(session: NSDraggingSession, sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext context: NSDraggingContext) -> NSDragOperation {
    if context == NSDraggingContext.OutsideApplication
    {
        return .None
    }
    else
    {
        return [.Move,.Copy]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the ALT (Option) key is pressed when returning the NSDragOperation.

Example:

```
if context == NSDraggingContext.OutsideApplication {
    return .None
} else {
    // get the current global event object 
    // and compare its modifier flags with ours
    if let event = NSApplication.sharedApplication().currentEvent
        where event.modifierFlags.contains(.AlternateKeyMask) {
            // ALT key is pressed
            return .Copy
    }
    // ALT key is not pressed
    return .Move
}
```

Comment: This worked.  In addition I needed to add this code to "draggingUpdated" as suggested by Kevin Low

Comment: In addition I had to add the key check to performDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo).  By the time this method is reached the drag operation is always .None. draggingSession(session: NSDraggingSession, endedAtPoint screenPoint: NSPoint, operation: NSDragOperation) does contain the proper operation.  So everything works by checking the key in  3 places, but my opinion is I should have only had to check in draggingUpdated, I suppose the default behavior is overriding this is some way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would keep your `draggingSession:sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:` function the same, since it only gets called at the beginning of the drag, whereas most applications with the copy/move functionality allows users to press option during the drag (and more importantly, while their cursor is over the row/view).

If you are using `NSDraggingDestination`, then you could check for this option key in `draggingUpdated:`.

If you are using an `NSTableView` or `NSOutlineView`, then you can check for this in their `validateDrop:` data source method.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this behaviour by using the following combination of flags in the `NSDraggingSource`:

```
- (NSDragOperation) draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session
  sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:(NSDraggingContext)context
{
  // This combination of flags gives the behaviour we want, somehow:
  //   - it uses move pointer by default (no plus)
  //   - plus appears when pressing Alt and drop is allowed
  //   - pointer stays unchanged when pressing Cmd and drop is allowed
  //   - pointer stays unchanged when pressing Ctrl and drop is not allowed
  //
  // If using NSDragOperationEvery, this is not the case as we then get
  // the plus pointer by default.
  return NSDragOperationCopy |
         NSDragOperationMove |
         NSDragOperationGeneric |
         NSDragOperationMove |
         NSDragOperationDelete;
}
```

(It's Objective-C but I hope the point is clear anyway.)